# check webservice if Empty

Tags: android

I have a web service and I wanna know if it's empty or not?? 
I wanna way to do this .. how to send request and print the response in a textView ??
I know gotta use `HttpConnetion`
but I'm confused about this class!!

Comment: Returns true?  getAttributeCount returns an int!

Comment: ya I know but I used a condition if return 0 setText True

Comment: what about getPropertyCount() ?

Comment: not defined in xmlPullParser!! how can i use it??@mihail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(urlName);

```
       HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
       HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
       inputStream = httpEntity.getContent(); 




       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
       StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
       String line = null;
       if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
       Data.servContent=stringBuilder.toString();
       }

       line = reader.readLine();
       inputStream.close();
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           System.err.print("UnsupportedEncodingException: " + e);
       } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
       System.err.print("ClientProtocolException: " + e);
       } catch (IOException e) {
       System.err.print("IOException: " + e);
       } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
       }
```